# std::partition segfault issue

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, quicksort, partition

Just for fun, I implemented a quicksort using `std::partition()` and was getting a segfault.  I found an example implementation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) which was only slightly different and works.  While I can see the advantage in efficiency in their implementation, I fail to see why mine is getting a segfault.  The only difference is that I am not doing a second `std::Partition` to avoid passing values that are the same as the pivot to later recursive calls.  Can anyone spot my issue?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename iter> void quick_sort(iter first, iter last)
{
    if ( std::distance( first, last ) <= 1 )
    {
        return;
    }

    auto pivot = *std::next( first, std::distance( first, last ) / 2 );

#if 0 //works
    iter midpoint1 = std::partition( first, last, [pivot](const auto& x)->bool{ return ( x < pivot ); } );
    iter midpoint2 = std::partition( midpoint1, last, [pivot](const auto& x)->bool{ return !( pivot < x ); } );
    quick_sort( first, midpoint1 );
    quick_sort( midpoint2, last );
#else //segfaults
    iter midpoint = std::partition( first, last, [pivot](const auto& x){ return ( x < pivot ); } );
    quick_sort( first, midpoint );
    quick_sort( midpoint, last );
#endif
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> to_sort = {2,1,7,4,6,9,2,1,5,8,9,4,7,4,3,7,4,8,3,8,9};

    quick_sort( std::begin( to_sort ), std::end( to_sort ) );

    for ( auto n : to_sort )
    {
        std::cout << n << ',';
    }

    std::cout << '\n' << std::flush;
}
```

Comment: You sort one-element range forever (or rather, until stack overflow). The range never reduces.

Comment: Would that not be caught by the `if ( first == last ) return;`

Comment: That checks for empty range.

Comment: if `first == last` becomes `true`, you are dealing with an *empty* range, rather than a range consisting 1 element

Comment: if I check for `if( std::distance( first, last ) <= 1 )` it still segfaults though...

Comment: When 1 is selected as the pivot, `std::partition` does nothing as the sequence is already partitioned. You then sort an empty range and the original range, over and over.

Comment: As is usual in quicksort implementations it is the off-by-1 issues, so easily written!, that get you.  In this case, slightly obscured by iterator notation.

Comment: This resolves the segfault at least but results in the sort not being correct:      `quick_sort( first, midpoint - 1 );
quick_sort( midpoint + 1, last );`  ....hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a sequence where the pivot you choose is the smallest element.

Then your partitioning will result in an empty sequence (where you stop recursing), and the original one.

Repeat until stack-overflow, or, with tail-call-optimization, the system wearing out.

<sub>As an aside, in the Code you say works, you used greater `>` once, though you should only use smaller `<`.</sub>

Comment: Aside Noted, fixed.  I will have to give some more thought to my termination conditions, or more likely, what ranges to pass to the recursive calls.

Comment: The other problem was that I was being stupid and forgot that std::partition does not actually ensure that my selected pivot is placed in between the values that are less and the values that are greater than it.  Instead it just ensures that all the numbers less than the pivot are on the left.  Thus the second std::partition is necessary to ensure that the pivot is where you expect it to be.